# How i can replace None value in list with int?

Tags: python

enter code hereSo, Basically I have a list with int values, and I want to see which values are missing in List. To do that I am comparing Value with a range from 1 to 9 (range(1,9)).

```
matrix = [None, 8, 3, 9, 2, 1, 6, 5, None]
```

when i run this code:

```
for row in matrix:
       if range(1,9) not in row :
                print(row)
        else:
            print('wrong logic')
```

I am getting this error

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: What's the value `matrix`? Is that the `list` variable that you have?

Comment: `if range(1,9) not in row and :` doesn't look valid. Can you show your complete code? What constitutes "missing"? Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: I am not sure if my logic is correct but, I am trying to see which values are missing from 1 to 9 in the list

Comment: fixed `if range(1,9) not in row and`  to `if range(1,9) not in row:`

Comment: `if range(1,9) not in row:` This line searches `row` for `range(1, 9)` the object. Obviously, it's not there because `row` contains integers, not `range`s.

Comment: By the way, `range(1, 9)` excludes the endpoint (9). You probably want `range(1, 10)`.

Answer (score 2):

We can see this as a difference of two sets, one with all numbers of interest and one with the numbers in your list. All you need to do is to subtract the set with all numbers by the set with the values in your list.

```py
list = [None, 8, 3, 9, 2, 1, 6, 5, None] 
missing_numbers = set(range(1,9)) - set(list)
print(missing_numbers)
```

This will print `{4, 7}`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `None`s from the list before evaluating whether the range is in the list.

```
start_list = [None, 8, 3, 9, 2, 1, 6, 5, None]
new_list = [item for item in start_list if item is not None]
```

And then check for numbers 1-9 in the new list.

Another way to do this without even removing the `None`s is to just loop through the numbers 1-9 and check if they are in the list.

```
start_list = [None, 8, 3, 9, 2, 1, 6, 5, None]
missing = []
for num in range(1,10):
    if num not in start_list:
        missing.append(num)
print(missing)
```

Comment: this is correct, you will get this `[4, 7]` result.
Now we know which numbers are missing. 
How can we replace `None` with `[4, 7]`? 
So want to add  `4` and `7`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by adding 4 and 7 - adding them to the list?

Answer (score 0):

the range function takes integers as its arguments. you cannot pass it a `None` value. You can convert your `None` values to zero's first.

```
my_list = [None, 8, 3, 9, 2, 1, 6, 5, None]
my_list = [item if item else 0 for item in my_list]
print(my_list)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[0, 8, 3, 9, 2, 1, 6, 5, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Requirement is not very clear but I suppose you want to compare values to list and finally print the missing numbers.

A possible approach to obtain the missing values in list_to_check is to compare if its entries are present in good_values and, if so, remove them from good_values.

What will be left is just the missing entries in list_to_check.

```
list_to_check = [None, 8, 3, 9, 2, 1, 6, 5, None]
good_values = list(range(1, len(list_to_check) + 1))

for number in list_to_check:
    if number in good_values:
        good_values.remove(number)
print(good_values)
```

Output

```
[4, 7]
```

> **Edit**

Now I read from comments that you would also like to add the missing numbers in place of the None items.

Here's a more verbose and easy to understand solution:

```
list_to_check = [None, 8, 3, 9, 2, 1, 6, 5, None]
good_values = list(range(1, len(list_to_check) + 1))

for number in list_to_check:
    if number in good_values:
        good_values.remove(number)

result = []

for value in list_to_check:
    if value is None:
        result.append(good_values.pop())
    else:
        result.append(value)

print(result)
```

Output:

```
[7, 8, 3, 9, 2, 1, 6, 5, 4]
```

For reasons that I do not fully understand if you are not using list comprehensions in your Python code you are simply not cool.

Let's also be cool, then!

Here's a shorter solution for the same problem:

```
list_to_check = [None, 8, 3, 9, 2, 1, 6, 5, None]
good_values = list(range(1, len(list_to_check) + 1))

for number in list_to_check:
    if number in good_values:
        good_values.remove(number)

print([good_values.pop() if value is None else value for value in list_to_check])
```

Output

```
[7, 8, 3, 9, 2, 1, 6, 5, 4]
```

Comment: Your code errors in multiple places. I don't see what you are trying to achieve; could you fix your code and elaborate some more? (Perhaps what `values` would be at the end)

Comment: I want to add the missing number, in the List.
Sorry, it was not clear.
IN this case `4, 7`

Comment: You are right but I am on mobile and everything is a big challenge... Maybe I will delete and answer from pc...

Comment: Ok I think I made it! Whew, hate coding on phone!

Comment: @Pitto I made an edit to fix `values` to be a `list` instead of a `range` and also simplified the line that removed the number from `values`.

Comment: Really thanks, even indenting a single line was pure pain. Never doing it again! :D

Comment: @iz_ range(1,9) already returns a list so there's no need to use list again :)

Comment: @Gurinder please check my updated answer and, if you find it useful, plase remember to upvote and/or choose it as final answer.

Comment: @Pitto Not in Python 3

Comment: Also, thought list comprehensions are good for creating lists, it's bad practice to use them purely for their side effects.

Comment: @iz_ I know, I was ironic in my comment about list comprehensions :)

Comment: Yours are actually very good points, changed my code accordingly. Thanks for the teaching!